# How to check whether a key is clicked Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a teleport orb in my game that you can hover over and click e to use to teleport to, however when I hold my e button down and hover over the orb it teleports me anyways, I want to make it so you have to hover over the orb and click e to teleport not so you can hold e and then hover over it. Any ideas on how to do this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class IsLookingAtTeleport : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource teleportsound;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    void Start()
    {
       
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Bit shift the index of the layer (8) to get a bit mask
        int layerMask = 1 << 8;

        // This would cast rays only against colliders in layer 8.
        // But instead we want to collide against everything except layer 8. The ~ operator does this, it 
        //inverts a bitmask.
        layerMask = ~layerMask;

        RaycastHit hit;
        // Does the ray intersect any objects excluding the player layer
        if (Input.GetKey("e"))
        {
            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
            {
                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * hit.distance, Color.yellow);
                Debug.Log("Did Hit");
                if (hit.transform.tag == "TeleportOrb")
                {
                    Debug.Log("Hit Teleportable Orb");
                    teleportsound.Play();
                    rb.transform.position = hit.transform.position;
                    Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject); // destroy the object hit
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 1000, Color.white);

                Debug.Log("Did not Hit");

            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Input.GetKey`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) is fired **every frame** while the key stays pressed.

What you rather want to use is [`Input.GetKeyDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) which is `true` only in the one frame when the button is actually pressed down.

Further note that instead of the stringed version I would always go for the ones using [`KeyCode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html) as parameter.

And then make sure you do your user Input in `Update` **not** in `FixedUpdate`. While the later might work in some cases for getting continous inputs such as `GetKey` you might miss single event inputs.

And finally whenever a `Rigibody` is invoved you do not want to set anything through the `Transform` component.

```
// Rather configure the desired layers you want to hit here
// via the Inspector in Unity!
// actually way better than just including everything rather only 
// select these layers that actually should be considered as teleport targets
// This way you wouldn't even need to check for Tags!
// just rather place all your teleport objects on a Teleport layer
// and only use a raycast on that layer
// see https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html
[serializeField] private LayerMask hitLayers;

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    { 
        // store the ray once
        var ray = new Ray(rigibody.position, rigidbody.rotation * Vector3.forward);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray , out var hit, Mathf.Infinity, hitLayers))
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * hit.distance, Color.yellow);
            Debug.Log("Did Hit");

            // Rather use CompareTag instead of string based ==
            if (hit.gameObject.CompareTag("TeleportOrb"))
            {
                Debug.Log("Hit Teleportable Orb");
                teleportsound.Play();
                rb.position = hit.transform.position;
                // destroy the object hit
                Destroy(hit.gameObject);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 1000, Color.white);
            Debug.Log("Did not Hit");
        }  
    }
}
```